# How to download an image from Azure DevOps Services HTML Field using API

Tags: azure-devops

I want to download Work Item details from our Azure DevOps Services instance and push it into our local TFS Server.

I got as far as connecting to the DevOps server using the **WorkItemTrackingHttpClient** in C#.
I can iterate through the work items i find and can see the fields, download attachments using **GetAttachmentContentAsync**. So far all good.

The last detail i need to complete this is to also copy/download the embedded images that are in the HTML Description fields. I can extract the HTML code from the HTML field and see one or more img src lines in it.

```
<img src=\"https://dev.azure.com/tenant/projectguid/_apis/wit/attachments/d928c8ee-f493-4d30-99a5-f62b7f36a2f7?fileName=grafik.png"\>
```

All of these have the fileName **grafik.png**, but a different fileGuid.

I tried to use the **GetAttachmentContentAsync** to download on this guid, but that did not work.
I tried to download the file using a normal Stream, but that didnt work, i assume this is due to authentication.
The image files also do not show up as a normal attachment.

So the question is, how can i download this image from Azure DevOps from my C# client, which is authenticated using a PAT through the API. Is there an API call i can use to download this file ? i have not been able to find it, or can i somehow authenticate the WebClient with that PAT so that it can download it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further troubleshooting, now the **GetAttachmentContentAsync** is able to download the image.

For anyone what might be looking for a similar solution. This is what i did

- Connect to TFS using the standard instructions -
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/work-item-quickstart?view=azure-devops
- Extract the img src URL's from the HTML Code
- Extract the GUID from the URL and download this image

Code used to download

public string DownloadAttachment(string url, string fileName, int workItemId)

```
    {
        string[] urlSplit = url.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int index = urlSplit.Length - 1;
        Guid attGuid = new Guid(urlSplit[(index)]);

        if (fileName == string.Empty)
        {
            fileName = urlSplit[(index)] + ".png";
        }
        return DownloadAttachment(attGuid, fileName, workItemId);
    }

    public string DownloadAttachment(Guid attGuid, string fileName, int workItemId)
    {
        var credentials = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, this.personalAccessToken);

        // create instance of work item tracking http client
        using (var httpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(this.uri, credentials))
        {
            Stream attStream = httpClient.GetAttachmentContentAsync(attGuid).Result;

            string folderPath = @"C:\Temp\WorkItemAttachments\" + workItemId;
            string fileFullPath = folderPath + "\\" + fileName;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

            using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                attStream.CopyTo(writeStream);
            }
        }

        return fileName;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)